# Are sausages made using the whole body of a chick?

Tags: food-safety, meat

I have seen [videos](http://youtu.be/QU6dTVKNV7E) that chicks are going into a grinder alive. (Please don't watch this video if you are a sensitive person.)

Is it true that sausages are made this way, with all the body parts of a chick, (like bowels, feathers, and things people don't eat)?

Comment: Rule #1 on the Internet: Don't believe every video you see. (The same applies to trustng other "information" from the web, btw.)

Comment: The answer is simply no. Sausages are not made by throwing live animals into meat grinders.

Comment: People eat sausages, so by definition every part that is in a sausage is a part people eat.

Comment: (note: I don't plan on watching the video).  Sausage in the US does not have bones or feathers in it.  Most don't have organ meats, either.  (those that do don't use all of the entrails, though).  I don't know if there's a class of chicken product that has feathers on it.   At least in the US, you're not supposed to have entrails or feathers in 'chicken meal' (which is used in pet food).  I've also heard of feathers and other "waste" parts of poultry ground up and being used in bioreactors to produce fuel.  And I have no idea how carcasses were disposed of during the avian flu epidemic.

Comment: I *do* know that for the avian flu, chickens that were in barns were suffocated before disposal.  (they'd shut off the fans to kill the whole flock.  I've heard it's not the most humane way to go, but it was better than the other alternative (starvation, where they could go cannibal).

Comment: [Sausage in a bun](https://discworld.fandom.com/wiki/Sausage-in-a-bun).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

First, most sausages are made from ground pork, not ground chicken. Second, most chickens that we eat are not killed as chicks but when they are larger. Third, in the vast majority of countries there are rules around cleaning animal carcasses before using them, such as removing at least the bowel contents if not the guts themselves. There are also rules about being humane to the animals. Putting live animals straight into a grinder would violate these rules.

But even if you don't believe in government inspectors, ask yourself - why make a nasty sausage with feathers, bones, and poop in it? Who would buy that a second time? And why waste (assuming by chick you meant a large fullsize chicken) the parts you can sell at a much higher price per pound or kg than you can sell sausages? It makes way more sense to remove the breasts and legs, and use the wings, back, neck etc in your cheaper dishes. Which, as I said in my first point, are probably not sausages because chicken sausages are unusual.

It seems the videos of very tiny chicks (just hatched) going into a grinder are real, but the output of the grinder isn't used for sausage or any other human-consumption. This is done for male chicks in egg-producing operations. The output of the grinder may go to pet food or simply be disposed of. Apparently the grinder is considered more humane than putting a bunch of live chicks in a plastic bag until they suffocate, or some of the other culling options. See [Jefromi's Wikipedia link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chick_culling) for more.

Comment: You're right (+1) but in *some* countries the disposal of male chicks of egg-laying breeds isn't as humane as you might like. The OP should be specific as to what country. That doesn't for a moment mean they end up in the (human) food chain, but does explain the misleading videos.

Comment: And the best starting point is probably just [the wikipedia article on chick culling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chick_culling). You can also find a lot of news articles from various points at which videos like this have gone viral, though you have to be careful there because a lot of them are pretty hyperbolic as well.